# JCodec: FrameGrab8Bit.class not included in JAR download - how do I add it?

Tags: jcodec

I just downloaded the latest version of JCodec: JCodec-0.1.9. However, I noticed the manifest doesn't include `FrameGrab8Bit.class`. As `Picture` has been deprecated and supplanted by `Picture8Bit` it would be nice, and almost necessary, to have access to the methods of `FrameGrab8Bit`. As the file is not included in the JAR, I was wondering how I could easily add the mising file to the JAR (I'm using Windows 10), or if there is another way I could add the file to the project.